# How can I do an arbitrary level of recursion in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, recursion, model

I have a blog post model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class BlogPost extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = "ID";
    public $useDbConfig = 'dev_blog';
    public $useTable = 'posts';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'BlogComment' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'comment_post_ID',
            'className' => 'BlogComment',
            'order' => 'BlogComment.comment_date DESC',
            'conditions' => array(
                'BlogComment.comment_approved' => '1',
                'BlogComment.comment_parent' => 0
            )
        )
    );
}
```

And a blog comment model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class BlogComment extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = "comment_ID";
    public $useDbConfig = 'dev_blog';
    public $useTable = 'comments';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Children' => array(
            'className' => 'BlogComment',
            'foreignKey' => 'comment_parent',
            'order' => 'Children.comment_date DESC',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Children.comment_approved' => 1
            )
        )
    );
}
```

In the controller, I set recursion on BlogPost equal to 2 and did a find:

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'BlogPost.ID' => $postID,
        'BlogPost.post_status' => 'publish'
    ),
);
$post = $this->BlogPost->find('first', $options);
```

What this does is get the content of a particular blog post, all root comments and one level of replies to the root comments.  It doesn't get a reply to a reply, though.  How can I retrieve an arbitrary depth of replies?

Comment: Using a large number of recursions is likely to lead to an unnecessarily large number of queries. It might be better to write a `find` query to fetch all the relevant comments after retrieving your `BlogPost` and then manipulating the comments into the correct form using the `Hash` utility.

Comment: Always a good idea to include a tag for which version of CakePHP you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use `recursive` at all.  Ever.

Set it to -1 in the AppModel:

> public $recursive = -1;

Then forget you even heard of it, and use CakePHP's awesome [Containable Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3A673664%20containable) to get the data you need.

**Note:**  See the [MANY other answers related to using CakePHP's Containable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3A673664%20containable).